# Image histogram equalization using variational calculus

Tags: calculus-of-variations, image-processing

In an image processing course at Coursera.org, on the section on PDE and calculus of variations, the professor gave the following as the functional to be optimized for image histogram modification:

U(I) = 0.5*∫[I(x)-0.5]2dx - 0.25*∫∫[I(x)-I(z)]dxdz

I(x) and I(z) being the new and original images, respectively

I'm not sure how to go about calculating and implementing the Euler-Lagrange for this functional. It would be great if someone gave me a few pointers.

(This is not homework, by the way, I'm just trying to implement things stated in the lectures to get a hang of things.)

Thanks in advance